# Terminal colors don't show

Tags: command-line, cinnamon, bashrc, 15.10

So, have the following in my `~/.bashrc` to display my git branch if one exists (works). When I save the file and run `source ~/.bashrc`, the colors don't show up. All I have is a white on black terminal but it does display the current branch. does this only work when I ssh into a server? From things I have read everyone is sshing into a server. If so how can I get it to work locally?

```
force_color_prompt=yes

parse_git_branch() {
    git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
}
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[01;31m\]$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w$(parse_git_branch)\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt
```